# Convert JSON to URI request API C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, json.net

I have a JSON:

```
{title:"hello", category: 11, products: [{code : '001', name: 'pen'}]}
```

I want to convert it to URI reqquest as

```
http://example.com/?title=hello&category=11
```

How to do it in C#?

Comment: Which part of the approach you already tried doesn't work as expected?

Comment: When I sent paragam to API C#

Comment: @LyThanhNgo you can deserialize the json and build the url?

Comment: @Sajid i can not send json requests to api :'( so i decide use URI

Comment: @LyThanhNgo, so you have a json, deserialize it and construct the url like you want, what is the problem with this?

Comment: is it a dynamic json or some strongly typed? - meaning will those 2 properties ever change from `title` to `name` etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct `url` from json, by using [`JObject`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm) for example, like the following code:

```
string json = @"{title:""hello"", category: 11}";
string url = "http://example.com/";

JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(json);
IEnumerable<string> nameValues = jObject
    .Properties()
    .Select(x => $"{x.Name}={x.Value}");

url += "?" + string.Join("&", nameValues);

Console.WriteLine(url);
```

**Result**

```
http://example.com/?title=hello&category=11
```

I hope you find this helpful.

Comment: If i want to sent array? How i do?

Comment: Don't forget that `Value` needs to be url encoded

Comment: @LyThanhNgo what is the expected format for array in the url? can you give me an example for json with array please? we can call the method recursively to build the url for Jarray or Jobject

Comment: @Dusan so, after building the url we generate  a new ``Uri`` from the string url?

Comment: @Sajid 
{
  code: "P001", 
  note: "", 
  products: [
{name: "tea", num: 5.0}, {name: "pen", num: 9.0}]}

Comment: @LyThanhNgo and the url will be like what for `products`?, for example : `http://example.com/?**code=P001&note= &products...**`